# Can I use ZeroMQ with UNIX sockets in the same thread in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, zeromq, interactive-brokers

I am trying to use ZeroMQ to connect to a historical data server written in Python while I connect to Interactive Brokers' Trader Workstation (TWS) using C++ through UNIX socket in Linux. But I can't seem to get both to work at the same time. I tried to connect to the Python server using ZeroMQ first, and then to TWS once the connection is established. But after I connect to TWS, I can't seem to interact with my original ZeroMQ connection in any way. The connection with TWS would always lose whenever I provide the ZeroMQ socket to call `zmq::poll`. But if I don't include the ZeroMQ socket, `zmq::poll` works just fine with the file descriptor from the connection to TWS. I am not too experienced with either UNIX sockets or ZeroMQ, but is it true that I can't use ZeroMQ and sockets API in the same thread? I thought it would be simple to add ZeroMQ to the original Interactive Brokers socket client, but it is more complicated than I expected. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code: how do you setup pollitems array, how do you call `zmq_poll()`, how do you process the pollitems array afterwards and why do you think that the UNIX socket always "loses"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I figured out what's wrong now. To answer your questions, I was following what lpclient and lpserver examples in the zguide do and performing some standard REQ-REP commands. When I had the error, even calling something like `zmq::socket_t::setsockopt` would cause disconnection from IB. Later on I figured out the problem was caused by these ZeroMQ functions changing `errno`, which makes the sample program provided by IB thinks that there was an error in the socket connecting to TWS. Once I wrote some codes to backup and restore `errno`, the problem was fixed.